# How to refer Jquery in SharePoint Online Page layouts?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, layout, sharepoint-online

I am trying to refer Jquery file in SharePoint online page layouts.
But it is not taking that.
Could anyone suggest me where to keep exactly jquery file in sharepoint online page layouts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add reference to Jquery file in pagelayout under PlaceHoder tags:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
   <script src="/_catalogs/masterpage/test1/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Reference:

[​Adding jQuery to Your SharePoint Site](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/how-to-reference-jquery-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thanks Jerry. It worked for me.Also one more point where to write the Jquery code or Javascript  in Page layout?

Comment: You can write the JavaScript Logic Code still in PlaceHolderTag just under jquery reference.

Comment: I written  window.history.back(); it is not working. I kept this in one function and called in button click of page layout. Any suggestions.